# In R, turn off automatic update by data.table on identical data.frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, updating

*(In 
continuation of [Conditional Replacing with NA in R (two dataframes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51142016/conditional-replacing-with-na-in-r-two-dataframes))*

So basically, I have

```
idx <- c(1397, 2000, 3409, 3415, 4077, 4445, 5021, 5155) 

idy <- c( 1397, 2000, 2860, 3029, 3415, 3707, 4077, 4445, 5021, 5155, 
         5251, 5560)

agex <- c(NA, NA, NA, 35, NA, 62, 35, 46)

agey <- c( 3, 45,  0, 89,  7,  2, 13, 24, 58,  8,  3, 45)
```

and I put each of them in a data.frame and make a copy of these dataframes

```
  dat1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(idx, agex))
  dat1copy <- dat1
  dat2 <- as.data.frame(cbind(idy, agey))
  dat2copy <- dat2
```

and I want to check  whether for all cases **idy=idx**, **agex=NA**, if yes, then **agey** should be set to NA too (and this should happen ONLY for **dat2**, and not dat2copy, which should remain untouched from the NA transfer)

However after,

```
    library(data.table)
    setDT(dat1)
    setDT(dat2)
   dat2[dat1[is.na(agex)], on=.(idy = idx), agey := NA]
```

dat2copy is updated too and also has NAs at the same places as the updated dat2. What can I do to prevent this kind of double updating, or how can I store a  copy of the original dat2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure that `dat2copy` is distinct from `dat2` after conversion to data.table use the data.table [copy](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.11.8/topics/copy) function:

```
library(data.table)

dat1 <- data.frame(idx, agex)
dat2 <- data.frame(idy, agey)

# wrong - same addresses
dat2copy <- dat2
address(dat2) == address(dat2copy)
## [1] TRUE

# correct - different addresses but equal contents
dat2copy <- copy(dat2)
address(dat2) == address(dat2copy)
## [1] FALSE
identical(dat2, dat2copy)
## [1] TRUE

setDT(dat1)
setDT(dat2)
dat2[dat1[is.na(agex)], on=.(idy = idx), agey := NA]

identical(dat2, dat2copy)
## [1] FALSE
```

Comment: Thank you soo much, it works perfectly